# PhoneGap media() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I just want to play an audio file on click, but it doesn't work. I suspect the problem is with loading the plugin, but I can't find out how to load it correctly.
I've got my JavaScript code from some topic here:

```
  var my_media = new Media("sounds/open.mp3",
             function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); }
    );
           // Play audio
    my_media.play();
```

And then I added this `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />`into my `config.xml` file. I tried to add it at the end of it, next to default plugins, but it never worked. 
I created my project through PhoneGap desktop, not through the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after few months I've finally found the answer... I just didn't load the *cordova.js* script. I know it's kind of a stupid mistake but I swear to God it was written **nowhere** in tutorials I read that I need to include this file.